# Set admob refresh rate for android always 60 sec

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

i set the refresh rate of Admob banner to 12 sec from the admin site but i still get refresh rate of 60 sec.

I tried versus refresh rate but 60 is the lowest rate i succeed.

Did anyone encounter this problem? can i force programmatic to set 12 sec refresh rate?

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh it manually. For example in [webapp](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#Web_Integration) it could be done as:

```
setInterval(function() {
     _admob.fetchAd(document.getElementById('admob_ad'));
}, 12 * 1000);
```

I believe in native way there is also something similar. But admob is working in some strange way at all, so this also could be not a good solution. For example if their logic of advertisement fullfilment is on server with some queque with 60 sec interval and not less, then this solution also will fail.